# UIAlertView shows up late than i expect

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uialertview

I am using a `UIAlertView` for entering username and password credentials before the next modal view, that gives him access to files in his account, appears.

However, when I debug, I came to know that the "ViewDidLoad" method of the modal view is called before the alertView shows up, and hence the program crashes as the view is not able to get username and password.

Here is the code

```
-(IBAction) openShareFile:(id)sender
{
 if (!self.shareFileBrowser) {
    self.shareFileBrowser=[[ShareFileBrowserViewController alloc]   initWithNibName:@"ShareFileBrowserViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Verify your Credentials" message:@"Enter  Username & Password" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    self.alertView.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput;
    [self.alertView show];

    self.shareFileBrowser.domain=@"fidomoose";
    self.shareFileBrowser.delegate=self;
    self.shareFileBrowser.title=@"ShareFile Browser";
    self.navController= [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.shareFileBrowser];
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        self.popController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:self.navController];
    }
}

if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    if ([self.popController isPopoverVisible]) {
        [self.popController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    } else {
        [self.popController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    }
}
else {
    [self presentModalViewController:self.navController animated:YES];
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put your code for init of your view in the delegate method of `UIAlertView` like follow

```
-(IBAction) openShareFile:(id)sender
{
    if (!self.shareFileBrowser) {

        self.alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Verify your Credentials" message:@"Enter  Username & Password" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
        //Edit Two line inserted

        self.alertView.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput;
        [self.alertView show];
    }
}

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if(buttonIndex)
    {
        self.shareFileBrowser=[[ShareFileBrowserViewController alloc]   initWithNibName:@"ShareFileBrowserViewController" bundle:nil]; 
        //Edit two line deleted

        self.shareFileBrowser.domain=@"fidomoose";
        self.shareFileBrowser.delegate=self;
        self.shareFileBrowser.title=@"ShareFile Browser";
        self.navController= [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.shareFileBrowser];
        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
            self.popController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:self.navController];
        }
        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
            if ([self.popController isPopoverVisible]) {
                [self.popController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
            } else {
                [self.popController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
            }
        }
        else {
            [self presentModalViewController:self.navController animated:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:1

Just use the method `presentPopoverFromRect:` instead of `presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:` and give proper `CGRect` ivar instead of `sender`

This will definitely solve your problem :)

Comment: I tried, i am getting the following error : Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target <NewMessageViewController: 0xca40ba0>.'

Comment: your `NewMessageViewController` is released some how before it get called so find out where you init the view controller. and just see my edit.

Comment: There is one typo I have edited it. I put some line wrongly in alertView method :)

Comment: Thanks !!!! I am able to run it. I commented out the sender line because i dont need it for iPad right now (Though i'll keep your suggestion in mind). Also, there is one more mistake, it should be if(buttonIndex) and not if(!buttonIndex)

Comment: Oh k I am just do the code in my mind and try to get right but made mistake in logic so thanks for Point it out I m surly edited it Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You should change your app structure so that the modal view isn't instantiated (or pushed) until the alert view's DismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated: is called..